# jQuery animate opacity doesn't work within Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate, opacity

jQuery animate opacity doesn't want to play nice with Safari; for some reason when I set opacity within CSS directly, it is ok; but when I try to use jQuery animate it doesn't work. Any ideas/known problems?

**I'm editing an SVG tag directly, works on other browsers but seems to be an issue with safari**

Answer (score 2):

set te opacity in jQuery before the animate.

$("#offerd_desc li").css('opacity', '0');

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: [Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2WuKK/)

```
$('div').hover(function(){
$(this).animate({opacity:0.5},1000);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this

`$("#offerd_desc li").css('opacity', '0');`

Sets the opacity INSTANT to 0, you would use the animation();

```
$("#offerd_desc li").mouseover({
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0.5},500);
});

$("#offerd_desc li").mouseout({
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0.5},500);
});
```

Use stop() before you do animation, else it will cause flickering when you hover it fast.
and i strongly recommend to use speeds such as 200 - 500 ms, cause else animation will take to long time.